# Select feeds other select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, select, angular-material

I need to implement that when making a selection in a select it automatically feeds another select being the validation of the fields with formBuild

Try to perform with a (change) = "changeSelect ($ event)" in the first select to take that value and perform its setValue in the formBuild but the second select still does not show anything, it does not feed the field reactively

```
<ng-select class="ng-select custom" name="" formControlName="tipo_pessoa_emissor" [class.ng-invalid]="!agentes.controls.tipo_pessoa_emissor.valid && submitted" (change)="selectTipoPessoaEmissor($event)" #tipoPessoa>
        <ng-option [value]="1">Física</ng-option>
        <ng-option [value]="2">Jurídica</ng-option>
</ng-select>


<ng-select class="ng-select custom" formControlName="devedor_tipo_pessoa" [class.ng-invalid]="!devedores.controls[i].get('devedor_tipo_pessoa').valid && submitted" bindValue="1">
       <ng-option [value]="1">Física</ng-option>
       <ng-option [value]="2">Jurídica</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Try using the same formControlName

Comment: mind sharing some of your component code? the part that does the handling of the values should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I get g making a change in the input, sending or type of attribute, and the value that I want to replicate.

```
(change) = "inputByinputDevedor ('devedor_numero_documento', $ event)"

inputByinputDevedor (control: string, e: any): void {
    this.devedores.controls [0] .get (control) .setValue (e.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).